# Discrete math with SSNs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, algorithms

I am currently doing some discrete math and am completely stuck on two problems. They are both the same concept:

An SSN is a Social Security number.

How many SSNs have digits that sum to 2?
How many SSNs have digits that sum to 3?

These are 9 digit numbers with 0-9.

My attempt would be:

200000000
110000000

Do this multiple times but Im assuming theres a much more simple way and I just cant figure it out.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain what SSN is?

Comment: @KonradSzałwiński: US identification as in Social Security Number.

Comment: copper is correct.

Comment: For sum to $2$: Either one $2$, the rest $0$ ($\binom{9}{1}$ ways to do this) or two $1$'s, rest $0$ ($\binom{9}{2}$ ways to do this.  Or else look at Wikipedia, Stars and Bars.

Comment: So it would be (9 1) + (9 2)?

Answer (score 2):

This is related to how many way you can partition a number. When digits sum to $2$ then we can write: $2=1+1=2+0$ and $3=2+1=1+1+1=3+0$.
 So the number of ways you can write for $2$ is: $\binom{9}{2}+\binom{9}{1}$ and for $3$: $2\binom{9}{2}+\binom{9}{3}+\binom{9}{1}$.

Comment: Thank you very much. what does the +9 signify though?

Comment: That's the case when we have all digits $0$ except for one digit as $2$ or $3$ and since the number has $9$ digits there are 9 different ways to write it.

Comment: Oh okay that makes perfect sense.

Comment: That was a bit confusing so now I edited my answer.

Comment: This is not correct.  For sums to $3$ you need to consider the orders of $2$ and $1$ so need to double the $9 \choose 2$ term because it expresses the compositions (partitions do not consider order) $2+1$ and $1+2$ with a bunch of zeros.

Comment: Many thanks for pointing that out. I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_security_number), SSNs are issued in the form $abc{-}de{-}fghi$ where $de$ form a *group number* that is issued in weird order, but is is never zero,  and $fghi$ form a serial number in the range $0001$ to $9999$. 
Finally $abc$ has traditionally been related to area codes, but can nowadays (after the "randomization" introduced on June 25, 2011) also take other values, *but* it still cannot be $000$.
Therefore there is **no** SSN with digit sum $2$ and there are only **few** SSNs with digit sum $3$: They must have one of $001$, $010$, $100$ as area code, one of $01$, $10$ as group code and one of $0001$, $0010$, $0100$, $1000$ as serial number.  That makes a total of $3\cdot 2\cdot 4=24$ solutions.

Comment: D'oh, right. I shot too fast after noticing there is no solution for $2$.

Comment: According to that page, "The middle two digits are the Group Number. The Group Numbers range from 01 to 99", so that 10 is a valid number.
Also 0010, 0100, 1000 are valid for the last number.  Similarly, there is nothing preventing 100, 010 from the first number structurally.  However, since they must be related to area codes, "The Area Number, the first three digits, is assigned by the geographical region" and cannot be zero, it is possible that one cannot form a sum 3 SSN.